# How common are Namesakes?

Tags: namesake

In the comic *Namesake*, some people named after mythological or folkloric characters end up sucked into the corresponding world to fulfill their role in the story. I think it's fairly clear that with names like Jack or Wendy qualifying as Namesake names, not everyone with the appropriate name gets sucked into the corresponding world.

So how common is it for an appropriately-named person to end up a Namesake in the sense of having gone to Neverland or Oz or whatnot and come back with powers?

Comment: A suggestion: Might be a good idea to include a link to the *Namesake* webcomic. Makes it easier for people to see what you're talking about. In my case, it's been years since I read what had been posted at the time, but my vague impression is that Namesakes are pretty darn rare -- I think of it as being a rare condition; something like having a super-powered mutant gene that qualifies you to join the X-Men and be a superhero. (But I'm not posting an answer because I don't remember any dialogue that told us just how many Namesakes are usually alive and kicking at any given time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided it wouldn't hurt me any to reread the first few chapters of the [***Namesake***](http://namesakecomic.com/) webcomic by **Megan Lavey-Heaton** and **Isabelle Melançon**, and see if I could find just where the term "Namesakes" was first defined, and/or some of the rules for the phenomenon were explained, in dialogue. Here's what I came up with.

[This page](http://namesakecomic.com/comic/right-definitely-insane-) of the comic is happening shortly after heroine Emma Crewe literally disappeared into thin air in downtown Toronto (as witnessed by her younger sister Elaine and their good friend Ben, who is the guy wearing a Green Lantern T-shirt). Jack Wright, a member of the secret organization known as Calliope, was also on the scene. Ben and Elaine took him back to Ben's house, and now are trying to interrogate him about what has happened to Emma. This page picks up just after Jack has introduced himself by saying: "My name's Jack Wright. I'm a Namesake."

[image]

For our purposes, I think the key bit is in the panel in the bottom left corner, where Jack Wright is saying:

> "We're called Namesakes because the ability to travel to those
>   subworlds are distributed at random among people with the same name.
>   Like, an Alice will always to go Wonderland. Each generation, a new
>   namesake is called to their related world in order to maintain
>   balance."

Of course, we should bear in mind that this was very early in the webcomic's run, and there might be subtleties that Jack didn't even know about (or wasn't bothering to mention to two people whom he had just met). But, if we take his lecture at face value, the implications seem to include the following:

1. No one has any way of knowing in advance just when and where a new Namesake will be born. It's random -- which means the Namesake characteristic doesn't just "breed true" in certain families, over and over, most of the time. Although, as I recalled -- and a little online research confirms -- readers eventually learn that it *can* happen that one Namesake is descended from another. But if that happened *most* of the time, then Jack wouldn't call it "random," would he?
2. There's a quota and a schedule. Only **one** "Alice Namesake" will be born in any given generation, somewhere among all the zillions of other girls who are born within, let's say, a 25-year range, and who are likewise given the name "Alice." *None* of those other girls will ever make it to Wonderland; it simply isn't their destiny. Note that a quota of one per generation *apparently* does not preclude the possibility of multiple "Alice Namesakes" being alive simultaneously -- as long as they are, let's say, roughly 25 years apart in age? (Give or take some margin of error.)
3. Jack thinks he knows *all* of the given names which have been used by Namesakes of previous generations. I say that because of this bit from the very next page of the webcomic:

   [image]

Notice that he **didn't** say: "Offhand, I'm not familiar with the history of any previous 'Emma Namesakes.' So I need to call it in to Headquarters and ask them to check our files to see if there have, in fact, been any -- before your sister manifested her ability today. After all, there are about *ten thousand* names linked to Namesakes; I can't possibly keep 'em all straight in my head!"

Instead, he made a categorical statement that there has never before been an "Emma Namesake." Ergo, this is something new to add to the official list! (But he's taking it calmly enough to suggest that this sort of thing is *expected* to happen from time to time; he certainly isn't gasping in shock at how unprecedented the situation is.)

So, if Jack can easily keep track in his head of all the known names linked to Namesakes, and if he is positive that "Emma" was not on that list before today, that suggests to me that the list is fairly short. Perhaps no more than 200 names at the outside? Which would mean that most boys and girls, after being born and receiving given names not on the list, are almost certainly never going to be Namesakes. Although, as I said, Jack's reaction to Emma's status suggests that *once in a blue moon*  Calliope uncovers another "first-generation Namesake" who should be added to their files.

Admittedly, an upper limit of 200 is just a guess on my part, since I don't know how good Jack's memory is. But I think it's clear that -- as far as Jack knows -- Namesakes in any given generation of the world population are very scarce indeed.